# Flex where to find alert object in an ApplicationInstance(applicationInstance.systemManager.rawchildren)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, flex3

As one of my window has popped up an alert and got closed so i dont have its alert object to close.
Found solutions to use applicationInstance.systemManager.rawchildren. But where would i find alert object in childList.

Answer (score 0):

It is a litte bruteForce method you want to do.
What you can do is simply loop through the rawChildren list and check if one of the childs is from type Alert.

```
for(var i:uint = 0; i < rawChildren.numChildren; i++)
{
     if( rawChildren.getChildAt(i) is Alert )
     {
          //magic goes here
     }
}
```

It would be far better if your application opens alerts at one location. Measn that you pass an event or comment (depends on your application framework) to display an error. This way only one controller can open/control alerts.

Comment: Do you open the alert with an parent sprite? When you don`t specify a paren then the will the alert be created at Application.application.document